# Read logs when using testflight app?

Tags: ios, debugging, testflight, cloudkit

How am I able to read logs when using tesflight app? App is not crashing. I can not find any crash log in Devices. Any other idea? How do you check if something wrong with i.e. in CloudKit but only in testflight app not when running in debug mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use a logging framework if you want logging for a release build. There are many frameworks available that support loging for release builds. You may like:

- [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack): stable and traditional

> *"It is similar in concept to other popular logging frameworks such as log4j, yet is designed specifically for Objective-C, and takes advantage of features such as multi-threading, grand central dispatch (if available), lockless atomic operations, and the dynamic nature of the Objective-C runtime."*

- [LibComponentLogging](https://github.com/aharren/LibComponentLogging-Core/): beautiful and hardcore, used by RestKit

> *"LibComponentLogging is a small logging library for Objective-C applications on Mac OS X and the iPhone OS which provides conditional logging based on log levels and log components. Additionally, different logging strategies can be used, e.g. writing log messages to a file or sending them to the system log, while using the same logging interface."*

- [NSLogger](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger): fancy with a dedicated visualization OS X App

> *"NSLogger is a high perfomance logging utility which displays traces emitted by client applications running on Mac OS X or iOS (iPhone OS). It replaces your usual NSLog()-based traces and provides powerful additions like display filtering, image and binary logging, traces buffering, timing information, etc."*

Comment: How do you get these logs out of a random TestFlight user?

Comment: I think you should then log to a file (NSLogger can do that) and decide when you want to sent it and how. For instance you could use Firebase (fabric) and send it as a non critical. Or you could send it to your own API endpoint